# Test Symfony 2.8 API with OAuthServerBundle

Tags: symfony, oauth, phpunit

I have an API endpoint that is already tested like this:

```
/** @test */
public function an_user_can_get_all_students()
{
    $client = static::createClient();

    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/api/students');
    $data = json_decode($client->getResponse()->getContent(), true);

    $this->assertStatusCode(200, $client);
    $this->assertCount(5, $data);
}
```

My test is green so far. But I added the `OAuthServerBundle` to protect that uri `/api/students`. What's the best way to authenticate my test?

**security.yml**

```
# To get started with security, check out the documentation:
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        oauth_token:
            pattern: ^/oauth/v2/token
            security: false

        api:
            pattern: ^/api
            fos_oauth: true
            stateless: true
            anonymous: false

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/api, roles: [ IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY ] }
```

Comment: So show your config of OAuth Server Bundle and security.yml, I understood, that you want to see 401 Unauthorized error?

Comment: I'm getting 401, but I wanna get 200 back.

Comment: So you should send token with your request. 1) Do you know how to get token from OAuthBundle? 2) Do you know how to use this token in request?

Comment: I've resolve using this: https://pastebin.com/jeFCfDbW, Could you take a look?

Comment: For my curiosity if you comment 5 and 12-14 lines it still works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer

You should send Access token in Authorization `header` with word "Bearer" before token:

```
Authorization: Bearer N2FmNzhhNGM2MTI5N2JhMWJlYj...
```

### Why your solution works

Your code from your link: https://pastebin.com/jeFCfDbW works because static method `createClient` use the same kernel than you in your 10 line:

```
self::$kernel->getContainer()->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);
```

you can check it reading code from: https://github.com/symfony/framework-bundle/blob/master/Test/WebTestCase.php. Next if you see at code of https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle/blob/master/Controller/AuthorizeController.php (lines: 50, 58) then you will see, that authorization origin from container.

So:

1) You share the same container between body of your test function and request processed by your client. This shearing is described in docs: https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html and you can prevent it by client method `insulate`.

2) You directly set `security.token_storage`

3) Then your request is processed with correct `security.token_storage` and authorization is successful. (AuthorizationController has correct token)

Probably lines 5, 12-14 are unnecessary because of API should not use session.

### How it should works in real live

In case of real usage your API client will send Token by Header with name `Authorization` and with value `Bearer TOKEN`. So to test if clients request is valid you should not set `security.token_storage` by hand but allow to OAuthServerBundle to set it from request. It is done in https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle/blob/master/Security/Firewall/OAuthListener.php in line 78.

You can find docs about setting headers in your client at https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html

In your case:

```
$client->request(
    'GET',
    '/api/students',
    array(),
    array(),
    array(
        'CONTENT_TYPE'          => 'application/json',
        'HTTP_Authorization'    => 'Bearer '.$token_as_string
    )
);
```

You can use

```
$client->insulate();
```

to test many access levels in one test function

Comment: Great answer! Yeah, lines 5; 12-14 are unnecessary. Back to your answer, how do I get `$token_as_string` you mentioned in your answer line 8? Sorry, but I'm totally new with Symfony.

Comment: Using `new UsernamePasswordToken`?

Comment: If your `UsernamePasswordToken` implements TokenInterface (https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle/blob/master/Model/TokenInterface.php) then you can get textual representation of token, by method getToken().

Comment: Great! Thank you!